# QGIS RGB2PCT is leaving holes in continuous regions

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I have a raster which was generated from an ArcGisMapServer layer, and is thus an RGB layer. I want to convert the RGB layers into a single 8bit layer in order to recover the original classes.

When I do this though, the one class always ends up with a speckled effect, even though the original data does not have this feature. Below is the raster after RGB2PCT as well as the original data.

This effect only occurs in the one class layer, not the others. Is there any easy way to rectify this?

[image: After RGB2PCT has run]
[image: Original Raster]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rgb2pct** uses Floyd-Steinberg "[dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)" - that's why you're seeing the speckled noise - the scattered white pixels. When you look at the raster from a distance, the white 'noise' pixels will disappear and the colour will look closer to the shade of light blue you're seeing in the water layer.

You might want to try [manually setting the colour palette](https://www.gdal.org/rgb2pct.html) you want to use, so that you use the exact RGB colour for the water layer colour.